# Error When Inputting Data to Be Written to File

Tags: c, file

So I'm trying to write a program that allows you to enter the voltage and resistance of a circuit and then works out the current of the circuit and writes it to a `.txt` file. Here is the code:

```cpp
void main()
{

    float V=0;
    float R=0;
    float I=0;

    printf("Enter your voltage value...\n");
    scanf("%f&V", V);
    printf("Enter your resistance value...\n");
    scanf("%f&R", R);

    I = V / R;

    FILE *f = fopen("C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/file.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
    
        fprintf(f, "%f %f %f\n", V, R, I);
    }

    fclose(f);

}
```

However, when I input my data I get the following error:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x566B96AA (msvcr120d.dll) in first project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000."

Does anyone know what this means and how I can fix it?

Comment: scanf("%f&V", V); should be scanf("%f", &V)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Raghu said in the comments, you need to change 
 `scanf("%f&V", V);` to 
 `scanf("%f", &V);` 
 and the same goes for `scanf("%f&R", R);` 
 Change to `scanf("%f", &R);`

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking over the entire program and it comes down to a silly mistake, damn.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to mention here.

1. A format string, when supplied with `scanf()` should match the exact input.
2. To *store* the scanned value into a parameter, you need to pass the address of the same as the argument.

So, basically. your input command should be

```
scanf("%f", &V);
```

and

```
scanf("%f", &R);
```

instead of

```
 scanf("%f&R", R);
```

and

```
scanf("%f&V", V);
```

That said,

1. You should always check the return value of `scanf()` and family of functions.
2. `void main()` is not pretty much correct. You should use `int main(void)` istead.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the address of your variables in the second parameter of `scanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float V=0;
    float R=0;
    float I=0;
    printf("Enter your voltage value:");
    scanf("%f",&V);
    printf("\nEnter your resistance value:");
    scanf("%f", &R);
    I = V / R;

    FILE *f = fopen("C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/file.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(f, "%f %f %f\n", V, R, I);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```